# Problem with order of variables and Id's for document.getElementById

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to work it out where a js script will pull the price (var) for different items (Id)'s on multiple html pages but what I'm working with only works if all the var's and in the same order as all of the Id's:

```js
function similarfunction() {

  var A1307 = 5.54;
  document.getElementById('A1307').innerHTML = A1307;

  var G2200 = 6.33;
  document.getElementById('G2200').innerHTML = G2200;

  var G5200 = 5.51;
  document.getElementById('G5200').innerHTML = G5200;

  var N3633 = 6.31;
  document.getElementById('N3633').innerHTML = N3633;

  var TS105 = 5.54;
  document.getElementById('TS105').innerHTML = TS105;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Test page</title>


</head>

<body onLoad="similarfunction()">

  A1307 is $<span id="A1307"></span><br><br> 
  G2200 is $<span id="G2200"></span><br><br> 
  G5200 is $<span id="G5200"></span><br><br> 
  N3633 is $<span id="N3633"></span><br><br> 
  TS105 is $<span id="TS105"></span><br><br>

</body>

</html>
```

If I change the 1st Id in the html page to something else, the rest doesn't work...

I'm a novice at best - just trying to find a way to update one js document that can apply site wide the Id is found

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If `document.getElementById()` does not find an element, then the reference to `.innerHTML` will cause a runtime exception. That's why the rest of the code fails. You can check the return value of `getElementById()` before attempting to use it as a node reference to avoid the exception.

Comment: And, use `.textContent` when the string you are working with doesn't contain any HTML, instead of `.innerHTML`.

Comment: Your problem is that an element's `id` implicitly becomes a page level property. Don't name variables the same thing as `id`s.

Comment: Do you know what I should put to check the return value of getElementById() ?

Comment: I've updated to .textContent, and that works but I don't know what to do to check the return value or how to fix the same name of the variables and the element's ID

Comment: @ContagiousBill If you don't how to check the return value of fixing the same name between a variable and an element id, you probably should take an online course or watch some tutorials to learn basic javascript. No offense, just a tip.

Answer (score 0):

The rest doesn't work, because there is no element with the id you've searched for. `getElementById` fails and the rest of your code was not executed, a classic `runtime exception`.
Change the name of your variables as well, because there could be a conflict between these variables and corresponding element id's. Use for modern browsers the `textContent` attribute, instead of `innerHTML`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Test page</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

function similarfunction(){

    var price_A1307 = 5.54;
    var span_A1307 = document.getElementById('A1307');
    if (span_A1307) span_A1307.textContent = price_A1307;

    var price_G2200 = 6.33;
    var span_G2200 = document.getElementById('G2200');
    if (span_G2200) span_G2200.textContent = price_G2200;

    var price_G5200 = 5.51;
    var span_G5200 = document.getElementById('G5200');
    if (span_G5200) span_G5200.textContent = price_G5200;

    var price_N3633 = 6.31;
    var span_N3633 = document.getElementById('N3633');
    if (span_N3633) span_N3633.textContent = price_N3633;

    var price_TS105 = 5.54;
    var span_TS105 = document.getElementById('TS105');
    if (span_TS105) span_TS105.textContent = price_TS105;

}

</script>

</head>

<body onLoad="similarfunction()">

A1307 is $<span id="A1307"></span><br><br>
G2200 is $<span id="G2200"></span><br><br>
G5200 is $<span id="G5200"></span><br><br>
N3633 is $<span id="N3633"></span><br><br>
TS105 is $<span id="TS105"></span><br><br>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the helpful answer here!  It's working on my test page - I'm going to update the universal js script page to pull the values for the Id's for different html pages, but this looks good to go - thanks again!

Comment: I just noticed that you've revised your answer - is this revised code better than your 1st answer / solution?

Comment: Yes. The current solution is more flexible, because you don't have to hard code the price of your elements in the code, instead you can assign it to variables like `price_N3633`. If you have to use the price a second time, you can just access the `price_name` variable.